# Are filters not matching incoming emails executed periodically? If so, when?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Whenever creating filters like "label:x" I am rightfully warned that **no newly incoming messages** will be caught, because once an e-mail is eventually labelled, it's no longer considered "fresh".

But, such filters are sometimes useful by making batch edits to e-mails with a label. If I were to do this in another way, I'd have to edit each and every filter that applies that label.

So, reaching my main point:

- if I create a filter, say "label:x", will it execute itself? If it will, when? After each e-mail received? Daily? Hourly? Every minute?

Answer (score 2):

Filters are applied only on incoming emails. An exception would be when creating a new filter, at which stage Gmail would ask if it needs to be applied as a one-time thing.